# preg_replace on certain conditions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to preg_replace some text but only if it's not commented. Here's an example of a given text:

```
// delete_me('First');
delete_me('Second');
/* delete_me('Third'); */
delete_me('Fourth'); // Some comment behind a command.
/* Tiny bit of comment */ delete_me('Fifth');
```

Now in this example I would only want the second, fourth and fifth row to be replaced. I want to replace the parameter with a new one. All the text is in one big string, separated by newlines.

I do have some preg_replaces to remove comment sections, but since I don't want to delete them it's not much use, but perhaps it helps someone helping me.

```
$text = preg_replace("/\/\/(.*)/", $replace, $text);
$text = preg_replace('!/\*(.*)\*/!s', $replace, $text);
```

Can anyone help me to replace the given parameters on lines that are not PHP commented? Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is impossible with regex. Its the same thing with HTML and Regex. You cannot simply match the Comments, as they may be in a string and you cannot match the strings as they may be in comments. What you need is the PHP Tokenizer.

Comment: That is not true. You can match strings within reason, see my comment below.

Comment: @TimWolla but you can use regex as a simple tokenizer...

Comment: `delete_me('is this /* commented? */');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split the text into chunks of comment and non-comment, then only alter the non-comment pieces, and finally glue them together:

```
$in = "// delete_me('First');
delete_me('Second');
/* delete_me('Third'); */
delete_me('Fourth'); // Some comment behind a command.
/* Tiny bit of comment */ delete_me('Fifth');\n";

$split = preg_split("#(//[^\n]*\n|/\\*.*?\\*/)#s",$in,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

foreach ( $split as $i=>$chunk )
{
    if ( $i%2==0 )
    {
        $split[$i] = preg_replace("/'.*?'/","'newparam'",$chunk);
    }
}

echo implode($split);
```

output:

```
// delete_me('First');
delete_me('newparam');
/* delete_me('Third'); */
delete_me('newparam'); // Some comment behind a command.
/* Tiny bit of comment */ delete_me('newparam');
```

The trick here is that the pattern supplied to `preg_split` matches the comment blocks, so you get an array of even/odd pieces of code/comment.

**caveat** This will of course break when you would put `/*` in a string literal.

Comment: Works like a charm, and a good theory. Did not think of that yet! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Will not work for `// foo('bar')`. A `// comment` does not have to be followed by a line break. And of course there are problems with quoted things like `foo('b//r')`.

Comment: Indeed does not work with comment inside the parameters. But it's not the biggest problem.

Comment: @Qtax: you mean when the line is the last line of a file with no newline at the end? Now *that* is a corner case.

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_replace("[^\/\*]+", $replace, $text);
```

Should work

Comment: What if you had line 1: "/* woohoo I commented the next line also!" and line 2: "foo (bar ()) */"

Comment: This unfortunately prompts an error: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\' - however the answer above worked. Thanks for the effort anyway. :)

Comment: Would you like to forget every single line that has a comment on it?